# How can this question be improved to agree with StackExchange model?

Tags: discussion

A few days ago I asked "[How much money would we save from going vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/281/115)", however the question got closed for being "too-broad". [Somewhere else](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/56/115) it was said that "there might be several good questions in there that could be asked separately."

Since:

- I'm kind of new to the StackExchange model, especially applied to social sciences (since Stack Overflow matter is less prone to "open questions")
- I'm not a native english speaker, and this has sometimes a **HUGE** impact on SE

Could you please be so kind to help me to understand how can I make good questions from the one I linked? You can also post questions yourself since I don't own property rights on this subject.

Comment: FWIW, for a non-native speaker, you have pretty good english. Better than some native speakers I know. Sometimes the phrasing is odd, but it's almost always grammatically correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem may lie here:

> Are there any scientific publications trying to estimate ... **one or more of the following**

You've started to answer the question (partially) within the question itself, by describing the factors which contribute to a financial savings. As I initially read it, you seemed to be asking for research which looked into the medical savings, *or* into longevity, *or* into reduced drug use, *or* into reduced disability levels, *or* other large-scale societal impacts. (And that's quite a lot!)

I see a couple possible ways to rephrase your question.

1. Simple: *What are the public health factors that influence the cost savings from a large-scale transition to vegan?* Since you've indicated an interest in answering it yourself, you can then list the various factors in the answer and list a bunch of references to back it up!
2. Ask lots of individual questions:

   - *What are the estimated public health cost savings from reduced cardiometabolic disease incidence resulting from a large-scale vegan transition?*
   - *What are the estimated public health cost savings from longer life spans resulting from a large-scale vegan transition?*
   - *What are the estimated public health cost savings from reduced drug use and disability incidence resulting from a large-scale vegan transition?*