# Are we reaching the limit of what is relevant to ask?

Tags: discussion, questions

A couple weeks ago we were getting 20 questions per day but that number slowing shrank and is now at 6 questions per day. My main worries about this website was that most people have the same questions and that many times answers are curated around circle jerking vegan groups and then shared on other groups, all this with little input of actual specialists.

Anyway, have we run out of questions to ask?

Comment: Hopefully this will get better now that the site is in public beta.

Comment: Number of visits went up a little bit, but number of questions is still but a trickle.

Answer (score 9):

Well, we're still in *private* beta, so it's possible the initial beta participants are running low on questions. (Whether that's accurate is probably too subjective to measure well. Personally, I don't have tons of questions that I was waiting to submit, but I am hopeful I'll compose more in future days.)

Six questions per day is still good for a beta, especially if they're getting answers. Once we're in *public* beta, that rate will hopefully increase.

Worth keeping an eye on, but I wouldn't panic yet :)

Comment: Well, so much for hoping the public beta would make things better. There was barely any change :/

Comment: @ecc - it's a well known thing that site activity decreases after public beta.

Comment: @Mithrandir why is that? one would expect that if it's open to more people, the number of visitors would increase. Anyway, is there anything we can do at this point?

Comment: @ecc - because there's less of a frantic scurry to ask enough questions to make it through to public, and not many people know about it yet. As for what you can do - advertise! Over at Literature, we've designed a few Community Ads that we posted on different sites. For Veg, I would definitely put one up on Seasoned Advice, not sure about any other sites. But promoting is very important.

Comment: Who can create ads?

Comment: Ads is a new meta question ;)

Answer (score 5):

I thought it was happening the same. For me too it was difficult to find new things to ask. Then I sat down and started thinking about new questions and made a big list (that I'm slowly publishing). Resuming, I think there are lots of things to ask (see [here](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/123/115) for example), we just need to focus a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fairly busy but also... (and my answer is probably not indicative of the majority):

I'm finding this site suffers from the same thing as the rest of Stack Exchange for me.  Questions and answers are subject to routine tearing down as soon as they are posted in many cases.

Probably this sort of format just isn't my thing, but that just kills my interest in participation, and gives me the rage :)

I realise it's about being a valuable Q&A source not a discussion forum, I just don't buy that that's always the motive.

Comment: That is something observed throughout the sites of SE. Your post will quickly be edited and voted on by the so called "power users". That is actually encouraged once you have access to the review queues. Anyway, we're now down to 4 questions per day. I hope the open beta comes soon otherwise we'll be down to a question per week in a few more days

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @ecc I hope so too, I see your wish has been granted already so let's hope that brings some new questions.  I could have predicted the downvotes as I wrote it, but some reasons would be nice from those that did.  The irony would be too much?