# We're going public! Are we attracting enough users?

Tags: discussion

Well done so far, we've gone public now. *But not all is well.*

We have very few visits every day, and we have few users in total. There is a great quality of questions and answers, but quantity is not our strength. [Have a look at our Area51 page.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94068/veganism-vegetarianism)

Now it seems [people are hoping that by going to public beta, more users and questions will come](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/129/47).

I'm not so sure about that.
Have a look at [the list of users, beginning with the newest one](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate). Doesn't look like the great rush to me, yet (although, admittedly, it is very early to make predictions).

So my recommendation would be:

## Attract users!

Invite people you know, post on veggie forums, spread the word, talk about it. We need a lot of new users. Ideally active users who ask and answer, but already more people who upvote good content would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel like this topic is just not broad enough. It's not Nutrition, Religion, Health, Sustainable Life nor Physical Fitness. It's just a bit of each and it seems like it doesn't attract enough people that are don't already satisfy their needs with the other sites. I'm quite disapointed

Comment: @ecc, this is the only site that covers everything from a vegan perspective. What is missing in your opinion? How could we broaden the scope?